# Counting, counting subsets , binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Can someone please help me? I have started by changing the form of each one for example k choose 2 as k!/(2!*(k-2)!) and tried to show that all of them add up to n!/2!*(n-2)! which is the same as n choose 2 but i got stuck. Is this the right approach? If so how do i simplify?

Comment: The goal is a combinatorial proof, right?  So look for ways to choose $2$ elements out of $n$ given that there are $k$ "special" options.

Comment: "*changing the form of each one for example k choose 2 as k!/(2!(k-2)!)*"  You have missed a key part of the assignment.  You are asked for a **combinatorial** argument, not an algebraic one.

Comment: BTW this is a special case of the Vandermonde convolution identity, and the combinatorial argument generalizes.

Answer (score 3):

You are required to use a combinatorial argument to prove the identity.

Consider $n$ elements set $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$ and we are to choose $2$ elements from this set.

One way to do this is $\binom{n}{2}$.

Another way, would be to count separately.

First, count the number of $2$-subsets where both elements are from $\{1, 2, \cdots, k\}$. This is $\binom{k}{2}$

Then, count the number of $2$-subsets where both elements are from $\{k + 1, k + 2, \cdots, n\}$. This is $\binom{n - k}{2}$

We not counting some $2$-subsets though. This is the one where one element is from $\{1, 2, \cdots, k\}$ and the other is from $\{k + 1, k + 2, \cdots, n\}$. Using multiplication principle, this is $k \cdot (n - k)$.

Hence, $$\binom{k}{2} + \binom{n - k}{2} + k(n - k) = \binom{n}{2}$$

If you are looking for an algebraic proof:

$$LHS = \binom{k}{2} + \binom{n - k}{2} + k(n - k)$$
$$=\frac{k(k - 1)}{2} + \frac{(n - k)(n - k - 1)}{2} + k(n - k)$$
$$=\frac{k^2 - k + n^2 - nk - n - kn + k^2 + k + 2kn - 2k^2}{2}$$
$$=\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$$
because the rest of the terms get cancelled out.
$$=\frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$
$$=\binom{n}{2}$$
$$=RHS$$

Comment: I am talking about set $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$. I have updated the answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On a $2,k$ lattice, the left hand side counts the number of paths that pass through $(2,k)$, plus the number of paths that pass through $(0,k)$, plus the number of paths that pass through $(1,k)$ (as $\binom{k}{1}=k$ and $\binom{n-k}{1}=n-k$).

Answer (score 0):

> Combinatorically prove that 
> $~\displaystyle \binom{k}{2} + \binom{n-k}{2} + [k(n-k)] = \binom{n}{2} ~: ~2 \leq k \leq n.$

RHS is number of different ways of selecting $2$ items, without replacement, from $n$ items.

Assume that before these items are selected, **any** fixed subset of $k$ **distinct** items is formed.

Then, when selecting these $2$ items, there are $3$ **disjoint** possibilities:

- Both of the $2$ items come from the (fixed) subset of $k$ items:
  Number of ways that this can occur is $~\displaystyle \binom{k}{2}.$
- Both of the $2$ items come from the (fixed) **complementary** subset of $(n-k)$ items:
  Number of ways that this can occur is $~\displaystyle \binom{n-k}{2}.$
- One of the $2$ items come from the (fixed) subset of $(k)$ items, and one of the $2$ items comes from the fixed complementary subset of $(n-k)$ items:
  Number of ways that this can occur is $~\displaystyle \binom{k}{1} \times \binom{n-k}{1} = k(n-k).$

Note that the $(3)$ LHS terms exactly correspond to the above $(3)$ computations.  Further these computations (in effect) **partition** all of the possible subsets of $(2)$ distinct items, selected from the $(n)$ items.

This means that the computations represent **disjoint** collections of subsets of $(2)$ items, where the union of these $(3)$ collections equals the collection of all possible subsets of $(2)$ distinct items, selected from the $(n)$ items.

Therefore, from a combinatoric perspective, the sum of the $(3)$ LHS terms must equal the RHS.